# Finding empty textField in a textField collection

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So in swift 3, I just want to loop through the textField outlet collection and if a textField.text = "", then do something about it. I have done the following, but I believe there should be a more elegant solution, one where I won't have to use an array to check the empty textfields but check it straight from the textfield collection.

```
    @IBOutlet var playerNamesCollection: [UITextField]!

    //add names to an array
    var namesArray = [String]()

    for i in 0...8 {

        namesArray.append(playerNamesCollection[i].text!)
    }

   //and then verify that array
    for i in 0...8 {

        if namesArray.contains("") {

            print("missing a name")

        } else {

            print("all textFieldsFilled")
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter out the empty fields:

```
let emptyFields = playerNamesCollection.filtered { $0.text != nil &&  $0.text == "" }
```

or alter them in place:

```
let result = playerNamesCollection.map { (textField: UITextField) -> UITextField in
    if let text = textField.text, text == "" {
        // textField.text is "". Do whatever you need to do with it
        textField.text! = "Edited empty text"
    }

    return textField
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop on your array like this :

```
var namesArray = [String]()

namesArray = ["Pierre", "Jean", "", "Michel"]

for name in namesArray {
    if name.isEmpty {
        print("Empty name")
    }
    else {
        print("\(name)")
    }
}
```

**Output** :

```
"Pierre"
"Jean"
"Empty name"
"Michel"
```

Answer (score 1):

contains is correct, if you want to know if any of the strings is empty, but you don't care which one (contains stops at the first instance it finds).  You do not need to put it in a for loop.

If you want to know the index of each empty string use enumerated().flatMap

```
var namesArray = ["a","b", "", "c", "", "d"]
let emptyIndices = namesArray.enumerated().flatMap { $0.element.isEmpty ? $0.offset : nil }
print(emptyIndices)  // [2, 4]
```